# Polynomial expression for $\frac 1{2^n} \sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}(2i-n)^{2k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Let
$$F (n,k)=\frac {1}{2^n}\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}(2i-n)^{2k},$$
where $n,k$ are non-negative integers.

By numerical tests the expression is an integer polynomial in $n $ of order $k $:
$$ F(n,0)=1;
F (n,1)=n;
F (n,2)=n (3n-2),$$
and so on.

Is there a simple general expression for the polynomial?

Comment: That is a closed form. The sum is finite. I'd try expanding $(2i-n)^{2k}$ or computing some values and plugging them in into OEIS, in any case.

Comment: @ajotatxe I have edited the question to clarify what I meant by "closed - form expression".

Comment: This expression comes out in Exercise 7 of [UMN Fall 2018 Math 5705 Homework set 4](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~dgrinber/5705f18/hw4s.pdf), and also in Corollary 2.5 of [Stanley's *Algebraic Combinatorics*](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/algcomb/algcomb.pdf) (but these two appearances are actually easily seen to be equivalent: a closed walk of length $n$ on the hypercube is uniquely determined by its starting point and the $n$-tuple of "signless step directions", which $n$-tuple is clearly all-even).

Comment: If there is a closed form, then Stanley could not find it. On the other hand, the polynomial claim is interesting.

Comment: Ah, I see why it is a polynomial. You can count the all-even $k$-tuples in $\left[n\right]^k$ according to the positions of equal entries (more formally: the set partition of $\left[k\right]$ that governs which of the entries of the tuple are equal). For any given such choice of positions, the number of tuples is a polynomial in $n$ with degree $k$ (namely, a power of $n$ times a power of $n-1$ times a power of $n-2$ and so on). Feel free to expand on this in an answer -- I am stuck in bed with a flu and not at my most productive.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you very much for references and the idea of proof. I hope you post your answer as soon as you are well. I have no hurry with the problem. By the way I found a rather interesting pattern governing the coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: $F(n,k)/2^{2k}$ is equal to the $2k^{th}$ central moment of a Bin$(n,1/2)$ random variable. Maybe this connection can help you find some references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\omega $ be a $n$-dimensional vector with binary components $\omega_i=\pm1$ and $\Omega_n $ be a set of all such vectors, the size of the set obviously being $2^n $. The sum of elements of a vector with $i$
positive and $n-i $ negative components is $2i-n $ and the number of such vectors is $\binom {n}{i}$. Thus
$$
F (n,k)=\frac {1}{2^n}\sum_{\omega\in\Omega_n } \left (\sum_{i=1}^n\omega_i \right)^{2k}
=\frac {1}{2^n}\sum_{\omega\in\Omega_n } \sum_{p_i\ge0}^{\sum_i p_i=2k}\binom {2k} {p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n}\prod_i \omega_i^{p_i}  
=\sum_{p_i\ge0}^{\sum_i p_i=2k}\binom {2k} {p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n}\left (\frac {1}{2^n}\sum_{\omega\in\Omega_n }\prod_i \omega_i^{p_i}\right)
=\sum_{p_i\ge0,\;p_i\,\text {mod}\,2=0}^{\sum_i p_i=2k}\binom {2k} {p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n}.
$$

To proceed further one splits the last sum into partial ones over terms with particular count $l$ of non-zero $p_i$ and ends up with:
$$
F (n,k)=\sum_{l=1}^n T (k,l)n^\underline{l},\tag {1}
$$
where $T (k,l)$ is the number of partitions of a set of size $2k$ into $l$ blocks of even size, and $n^\underline{l}$ is falling factorial. $T(k,l)$ can be recognized as the OEIS sequence [A156289](https://oeis.org/A156289) with known close-form and recurrence expressions.

---

Note added: by numerical evidence  the polynomial (1) can be expressed in the terms of usual powers as:
$$
F (n,k)=\sum_{l=1}^n A (k,l)n^l,\tag {2}
$$
with $A (k,l) $ being the OEIS sequence [A318146](https://oeis.org/A318146). In other words $F(n,k) $ is in fact  the so called Omega polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

It  is convenient to use the  *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series. This way we can write for instance

\begin{align*}
n![z^n]e^{jz}=j^n\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{2^n}}&\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(2j-n)^{2k}}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(2k)![z^{2k}]e^{(2j-n)z}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{(2k)!}{2^n}[z^{2k}]e^{-nz}\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}\left(e^{2z}\right)^j\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{(2k)!}{2^n}[z^{2k}]e^{-nz}\left(1+e^{2z}\right)^n\tag{4}\\
> &=(2k)![z^{2k}]\left(\frac{e^{z}+e^{-z}}{2}\right)^n\tag{5}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(2k)![z^{2k}]\left(\cosh z\right)^n}
> \end{align*}
>
> We see OPs formula is essentially the coefficient of $z^{2k}$ of $\left(\cosh z\right)^n$ which does not have a closed formula as far as I know.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we apply the *coefficient of* operator according to (1).
- In (3) use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (4) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (5) we write the expression somewhat more conveniently.

Comment: I think I have found such a closed polynomial formula. See my answer below.

Comment: @user: A closed formula means there is no $\Sigma$ involved. Somewhat more concrete a closed formula in this context is a function in $n$ with a constant number of terms. When using something like $\Sigma_{j=0}^n$ the number of terms is not constant but increases with increasing $n$.

Comment: What was meant was a closed formula for the coefficients of the polynomial (which do not depend on $n $).

Comment: @user: I agree, you're right. (+1) for your nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

I'll play with the cosh and
see if I get 
anything other than
the original problem.

$\begin{array}\\
\cosh^n(x)
&=\frac1{2^n}(e^x+e^{-x})^n\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}e^ke^{(n-k)x}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}e^{nx}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}e^{-2kx}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(nx)^i}{i!}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-2kx)^j}{j!}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(nx)^i}{i!}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-2kx)^j}{j!}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{m} \dfrac{(nx)^i}{i!} \dfrac{(-2kx)^{m-i}}{(m-i)!}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}x^m\sum_{i=0}^{m} \dfrac{(n)^i}{i!} \dfrac{(-2k)^{m-i}}{(m-i)!}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}x^m\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\sum_{i=0}^{m} \dfrac{(n)^i}{i!} \dfrac{(-2k)^{m-i}}{(m-i)!}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}x^m\sum_{i=0}^{m}\dfrac{(-2)^{m-i}(n)^i}{(m-i)!i!}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}  k^{m-i}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^m}{m!}\sum_{i=0}^{m}\binom{m}{i}(-2)^{m-i}n^i\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}  k^{m-i}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-2)^mx^m}{m!}\sum_{i=0}^{m}\binom{m}{i}(-n/2)^i\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}  k^{m-i}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-2)^mx^m}{m!}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\sum_{i=0}^{m}\binom{m}{i}(-n/2)^i  k^{m-i}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-2)^mx^m}{m!}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-n/2+k)^m\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^m}{m!}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(2k-n)^m\\
\end{array}
$

And this is the OP.

Oh well.